# LG 25UM58 not working with MBP 16 2019

Tags: display

I have a LG 25UM58 ultrawide monitor. Whenever I connect it with my MBP 16 2019, it connects with an incorrect resolution. If I connect/disconnect my monitor a few times it automatically connects with the correct 21:9 2560 * 1080. Is there a fixed way of solving this other than switch res x?

Comment: How do you connect it, what kind of resolution is used when it is incorrect? Did you already try to replace the cables/plugs?

Comment: Perhaps connecting with a different type of cable (e.g. DisplayPort vs HDMI) would be worth trying, if you don’t find anything in the monitor’s settings menu that helps.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of cables so didn't try changing any.